# How to concatenate a String with AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a URL (which is a String at the moment), I have query parameters which I want to add to the URL which are of the type AnyObject. Can anyone advise the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"\(yourVariableHere)"` format to treat them as string.

```
var domain:AnyObject = "http://www.yourdomain.com/"
var parameter:AnyObject = "?id=5"
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(domain) \(parameter)")
```

[More info on Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

```
let string1 = "hello"
let string2 = " there"
var welcome = string1 + string2
```

Comment: Please mark the question as answered so that other community members will also benefit it from.

Comment: @AlexChesters This example is a perfect example why you shouldn't do it this way: actually, the URL is invalid. In order to compose a ULR from its components, use the helper class  `NSURLComponents`. Note that each component may require a different encoding - and will be cumbersome to accomplish "by hand". And that's why NSURLComponents exists.

Comment: I agree that URLs should not be constructed this way, but the question asks how to concatenate Strings.

Answer (score 1):

As an example from what @CouchDeveloper suggested:

```
let baseUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.server.com/")
let components = NSURLComponents()
components.path = "api/service.php"

let id = 23
let searchTerm = "Foo \" Bar"
components.query = "id=\(id)&search=\(searchTerm)"
components.URLRelativeToURL(baseUrl)
```

Notice it will automatically save you from query conversions of special characters.

Hope it helps ... maybe *the others*

Answer (score 0):

how are you doing the query? if its a normal NSURLRequest you can do something like

```
var server = "http://www.server.com"
var String1 = "users"
var String2 = "bob"

var myUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(server)/api/\(String1)/\(String2)")!

let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl)
```